# how can i split Nav menu item with border: 3px in Divi theme?

Tags: wordpress, menubar, divi, divi-theme, wp-nav-menu-item

How can i do this nav-bar Call to Action Button with border:3px in Divi theme ?

or Question: how can i split Nav menu item with border: 3px in Divi theme?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U17ZD.png)

#divitheme #divi #problem #AyanSujon

#wordpress

i want to create a "Call to Action Buttom"  in nav-menu with border: 3px in Divi theme wordpress.

split "NEED ANY SOLUTION" Button will be Right of the Header and others menu items will be CENTER and Header Logo will be Left.

thats it.